# wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 blank line

Tags: html, html-table, wkhtmltopdf, blank-line

**wkhtmltopdf version(s) affected**:0.12.6 (with patched qt)

**OS information**
Ubuntu 20.04 focal

**Description**
A blank line appears randomly, its a big file with thousands of lines like this, I searched for a solution but the issue was close and solved on an older version, but the solution was no showed

image of problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12gNkew8hVWvSasGbljQAfRWLm0ce045u/view?usp=sharing

**How to reproduce**

```html
<tr>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342921</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342922</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342923</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342931</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342932</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342938</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342948</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342951</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342952</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342953</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342957</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342959</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342964</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342969</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342973</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342984</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342985</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342987</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342988</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342989</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342991</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342992</td>
<td style='padding: 0.3rem'>342995</td>
</tr></table><br>
    <div align="right">
        <table>
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:600; text-align:right; padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px;">Total Vendidos:</td>
                    <td >171.573</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:600; text-align:right;">Total Extraviados:</td>
                    <td  >812</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:600; text-align:right;">Total Devolvidos:</td>
                    <td  >168.615</td>
                </div>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:600; text-align:right;">Total Vendidos + Extraviados:</td>
                    <td  >172.385</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```